# Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Tags: r, function, scope

I have defined `max()` function as below:

```
max <- function(...) max(...,na.rm=T)
```

But it fails to compute `max(1:5)` with following error: `Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?`

Watching the result in `traceback()` identifies the problem:

```
88: max(..., na.rm = T) at PositionMeth.R#1521
87: max(..., na.rm = T) at PositionMeth.R#1521
86: max(..., na.rm = T) at PositionMeth.R#1521
85: max(..., na.rm = T) at PositionMeth.R#1521
84: max(..., na.rm = T) at PositionMeth.R#1521
```

The new `max(...)` function is calling itself in the body, not the original `max()` function. A simple solution is to rename the function: `Max <- function(...) max(...,na.rm=T)`. Is there other good options without renaming -i.e. forcing R to run original `max()` function in the body of the new `max(...)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to call the original max function using its namespace, `base`:

```
max <- function(...) base::max(...,na.rm=T)
```